# Is hijama allowed during fasting on Ramadan?

Tags: sunni, sunnah, sawm, ramadan

I want to know if it's allowed while fasting according to the Quran and Sunnah to do hijama during the month of Ramadan?

Comment: Seems to be a perfectly valid question to me. I think the intent of the question is implied: the questioner may mean during fasting hours. So there's nothing non-specific about the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

source: https://www.facebook.com/HijamahReviveASunnah/posts/610131989008138

Here is one narration....

> "The cupper and the one being cupped have broken their fast." [Saheeh see Irwaa al-Ghaleel (931)].

However, this hadith abrogated as Sheikh al-Albaani and ibn Hazm (may Allah have mercy upon them) showed by the following hadith:

> Abu Sa'eed al-Khudhree r.a said, "The Messenger s.a.w validated cupping for the fasting person." [Saheeh see Irwaa al-Ghaleel (4/74)].

Another narration:

> Abdullah ibn Abbas r.a reported that the Messenger s.a.w was cupped while he was fasting. [Saheeh al-Bukhaaree (5694)].

Yet another:

> Anas ibn Maalik r.a was asked: "Did you dislike cupping for the fasting person?" He said, "No except for the reason of one becoming weak." [Saheeh al-Bukhaaree (1940)].

In conclusion, the 3 madhaahib are of the opinion that Hijama does not break the fast; whereas the Hanbali scholars are of the opinion that Hijama does break the fast for both the one who has it done and the one who is doing it.

[This page](http://1islam1.com/en/articles/does-hijama-(cupping)-break-the-fast.html) seems to cover and summarize the topic and the above Ahadith in a very logical and easy to understand manner.

Comment: Im well aware of these narrations.  The problem here is you're quoting things that aren't Prophetic saying, but rather secondary from some companions. Only theprophets actual words are cconsidered part of deen and not what the companions say.

Comment: @Sayyid: That's as incorrect as it can be. ANY Prophetic saying would be narrated to us through a chain of narrators, hence there's no point in saying that one of the Ahadith is a Prophetic saying and others are companions' sayings. Those companions are quoting the Prophet (SAW) himself or his actions, not giving their own opinions (except for the last one above). Even the Hadith that you quoted comes to us through Imam Ahmad or Abi Dawood (RA) etc. You don't mind accepting those narrations, do you?

Comment: No. Not a single one you posted are quoting the prophet.  The prophets actions don't overrule revelation.  Otherwise marrying more than four wives would be allowed since the prophets actions give evidence.   Yet, we're verbally forbidden.   His words always are the Deen that take precedence over his actions.  You should know the difference between wahi and non-wahi. Not to mention the first two narratives are fabricated and the other two aren't prophetic words.

Comment: @Sayyid: What're you saying? When a Hadith mentions that Ibn-e-Abbas (RA) reports that Prophet (SAW) was cupped while fasting, how does it become companion's opinion? There are only two possibilities: Either Ibn-e-Abbas (RA) is نعوذ باللہ lying about Prophet (SAW), or Prophet (SAW) himself is نعوذ باللہ going against the revelation, BOTH of which are impossible; repeat impossible. Therefore there needs to be a logical explanation that resolves the apparent conflict between first and remaining Ahadith. This explanation is provided in the link that appears at the end of my post. Plz check.

Comment: The hadith is falsely attributed to Ibn Abbas. And even if it was true, Prophets words abrogate his actions.  Revelation from Allah is always first revealed in words, I.e. Quran.  Something can be allowed until words make a ruling uponit.  I already explained it in the previous answer as to what scholars claim but cannot prove it.

Comment: @Sayyid: That Hadith is available in Sahih Bukhari, Book of Medicine (76), Hadith No. 16. Now if you're claiming that Imam Bukhari has falsely attributed this Hadith to Ibn-e-Abbas (whether deliberately or mistakenly), I really doubt you've any idea of the piousness and accuracy of that man and that book. As of your argument about abrogation, the Hadith that prohibits hijama during fasting PREDATES the hadith that allows it, so there is any abrogation, it is towards allowance, not towards prohibiting. Abu Saeed Khudri's narration uses the word رخص, which means allowed after having prohibited.

Comment: @Sayyid: I'd once again suggest that you read the article available at the link provided at the end of my posting.

Answer (score 1):

*Hijama* is allowed during *Ramadhan* but **not** while you're fasting.

The Prophet was reported to have said =

> "The cupper and the one for whom cupping is done both break their
>   fast."

(Musnad Ahmed, Sunan Abu Dawud, Jami at Tirmidhi, Sunan ibn Majah)

Many scholars made the claim that this was abrogated and used sayings of Anas bin Malik and Ibn Abbas to cancel the saying of Prophet Mohamed.

However, this is false as whatever the Prophet said was revelation from Allah and only revelation from Allah can nullify itself.  And there are no other evidences that say *hijama* does not break the fast.

Therefore, the safest route is to follow what Rasolullah said and not do *hijama* while fasting.

Comment: This answer provides quite one-sided view and in mixes author's opinion with facts. See my answer below that covers more Ahadith on the subject.